# Raw request and response to HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse, respectively

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I've been exploring the [codebase](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) for the last few weeks and I have yet to been able to find how to convert raw `bytes` to `HTTPRequest` or `HTTPResponse`.

Long story short, I would like to do something along the lines of (simplified for question sake):

```py
from mitmproxy.http import HTTPRequest

req = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n"

http_request = HTTPRequest.create(req)

print(http_request.method) 
# >>> GET
```

I'm 99% certain somewhere in the code base such actions *must* take place, but I've yet to find it. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing is done in https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/net/http/http1/read.py and https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/net/http/http1/read_sansio.py. Note that the latter will be merged in the former in a few days (we're just in the middle of a major restructuring) and some of the methods currently in read.py will disappear.

Comment: Understood, thank you. The project is indeed a bit hard to navigate through- hopefully this makes it easier. Though I'm not a contributor in the project, splitting the project into separately maintainable projects might not be a bad idea. A module in itself for manipulating HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 requests would be quite useful for other purposes (i.e [`httpsuite`](https://github.com/synchronizing/httpsuite)-like). In the meantime, thank you.